# Most efficient way to parse and reformat data with Nokogiri & Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

I'm working on reformatting HTML output from a search query for an inventory manager for a number of car dealers. There's no direct DB access, no information available from the service creators so I decided to attempts to parse and reformat the data with Nokogiri and generate new pages of results based on the search query.

On first load of the page, I'm just using a default search to generate the first results.

For the search to work, I'm sending the query to a URL like this:

```
post '/search/?:search_query' do
  url = "http://domain.com/v/?DealerId=" + settings.dealer_id + "&maxrows=10&#{params[:search_query]}"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css("td:nth-child(5) .ForeColor4").each do |msrp|
    session["msrp"] = msrp.inner_html
  end  
  doc.css("td:nth-child(4) .ForeColor4").each do |price|
    session["price"] = price.inner_html
  end
  erb :index    
end
```

I know there's got to be a smarter way to do this.

Edit:

An example URL to request data:

```
http://domain.com/?DealerId=1234&object=list&lang=en&MAKE=&MODEL=&maxrows=50&MinYear=&MaxYear=2011&Type=N&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=&STYLE=&ExtColor=&MaxMiles=&StockNo=
```

A description of the HTML generated:

Unfortunately, it's old code that's almost entirely table-based, has inline-styles and lacks classes or ids in most areas.

An example of a CSS selector:

```
td:nth-child(5) .ForeColor4
```

An XPath selector:

```
//td[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ForeColor4", " " ))]
```

I've also looked at mechanize or hpricot as possibilities but I'm not aware of the best tools for the job as I haven't attempted screen-scraping before.

**Summary**: I want to pull the data from the HTML, temporarily store it in a variable / session / cookie (data changes several times per day), and then be able to reformat the output into my own HTML/CSS styling.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a smarter way to do it as you didn't really give us enough background or data to work with. What is the URL you are retrieving or what does the page's HTML look like?

Comment: I've added some more detail / examples, thanks for letting me know what would be helpful.

Comment: Mechanize is great if you need to navigate a site through forms or logins. It's a toss-up for individual pages where you're scraping the HTML. Personally I like open-uri and Nokogiri for most of what I do. There are better, but more complex, HTTP clients than open-uri, but Nokogiri is hard to beat. A good alternate HTTP client is [`Typhoeus`](http://www.pauldix.net/2009/01/ruby-http-client-library-performance.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd decouple the scraping from the user action. Have an independent process scrape and fill your database. This will improve performance drastically, as the fetching, creating a DOM, parsing, then rendering output on every action is going to be slow.

Comment: The dealers will be both adding and removing from their inventory (I'm told up to a few times per day) so dropping everything in a database seemed like overkill to me when I'd still need to check for changes each time anyways.

Comment: @Anders H: Yes, you can check as often as you want, but you don't have to use up the user's time. Unless your users are willing to trade a painfully slow response time for the knowledge that their information is up-to-the-second.

Comment: That's a good point. If I just rebuild the database a few times per day there's a low probability anything has changed. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
  doc.css("td:nth-child(5) .ForeColor4").each do |msrp|
    session["msrp"] = msrp.inner_html
  end  
  doc.css("td:nth-child(4) .ForeColor4").each do |price|
    session["price"] = price.inner_html
  end
```

You might want to use Nokogiri's `at_css()` method instead of the regular `css()`. `at_css()` finds the first occurrence of your target and only returns that one node, similar to doing a `.first` against the nodeset that `.css()` returns.

That would simplify your lookups to this form:

```
session["msrp"] = doc.at_css("td:nth-child(5) .ForeColor4").inner_html
```

I'd probably add something like `rescue 'msrp lookup failed'` while testing to the end of the lookups just in case you've got bad accessors. Or you could let the code fail when `inner_html()` got mad trying to read from a nil. It's just a bit friendlier way to debug.

Otherwise your lookups seem to be decent.

Comment: I'm forced to use .css I believe because there's (up to) 10 search results per page. So the "td:nth-child(5) .ForeColor4" selector actually applies to 10 elements. 

I guess I'm just not sure whether I'm trying to do too much without using a database or PStore or if I'm overlooking a simpler method.

Comment: I agree with Mark Thomas, that a backing database is a good idea. Your backend code would run as a crontab job, say every four or six hours. You can ask their server whether the content changed, or do a checksum of the html retrieved and determine whether you need to process it. Cache your results in the DB. Another app would return the current results from the DB when requested.

Comment: Oh, in case you're not familiar with it, a HTTP `head` request is what you use to see if a document has changed. The `ETag` and/or `Last-Modified` headers will be your friends.